# Im unable to get System.IO.Compression dll for .net 4.0 , im trying to write a small script to zip old files in a server

Tags: c#, dll

I developed a small script in c# to zip old log files in the server , unfortunately the server does not have .net 4.5, i tried installing .net 4.5 on the server but it asked for a restart prior to installation ,installing and restarting of server is not encouraged since its an active production server with heavy load hence requiring approvals  , please help me on how i can implement the same functionality provided by system.io.compression/system.io.compression.filesystem on .net 4.0

Comment: use [SharpZipLib](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/)

Comment: Build you application under .net 4.0 using GZipStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net 4, 4.5 and 4.5.1 have not had any support (security updates or bug fixes) since January 2016 (over a year ago now). You are running a production server with outdated and unsupported software, you need to update 4.5.2 or 4.6 as soon as possible anyway, so just get permission to do the restart in order to resolve this vulnerability (and install 4.5.2 or 4.6, not 4.5).